# How to make a dropdown using bootstrap such the selected dropdown option now becomes the dropdown name?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

The options listed on the website do not change the dropdown name when a dropdown element is clicked

Comment: That is some stupid behaviour. [Take a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) maybe this will solve all the issues....

Comment: post the code you have tried

Comment: Yes, please post your code - what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly and I done have your code, Try the below code.

Hope this helps.

```js
 $(function () {

            $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {

                $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
                $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn">Please Select From List</button>
        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Class I</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Class II</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Class III</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Other</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```